# xCode Storyboard changes wont update application after update

Tags: xcode

I just updated xCode and am trying to update one of my projects, however, it appears that the changes i am making in the storyboard are not changing the application itself.

The story board still shows my changes but when i debug the app, it remains unchanged.

Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Or, if that doesn't do it, quit Xcode, purge the derived data folder, and then restart Xcode. If problem persists, update your question with details about what changes are made to storyboard and describe how you've identified that the app is not updating.

Comment: i started with attempting to clean it.  and all i want to do is change a label's font size and it will not even allow for that

Comment: Try the clean, derived data, else, check also that you're working on the correct StoryBoard, and not a localized one. I got tricked once.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do a deep clean that is `Shift + Option + Command + K`
2. Reset your simulator
3. Quit Xcode
4. Empty trash
5. Open Xcode and try again

Can be applied to most Xcode problems.

Comment: did that  and am now getting the error :    error: /Users/charlesiams/Desktop/Dan's Stuff/Captains Helm/DerivedData/Captains Helm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Captains HelmTests.xctest: No such file or directory